# Data binding not working in angular2-multiselect in reactive forms

Tags: angular, data-binding, multi-select

I am using an angular2-multiselect dropdown in a reactive form in angular 7.  I have a click button which adds more drop-down on click and then I am saving that data on click of save button. Eveything is working fine except that the data binding is not working. I am able to save the data but when I open the form again to edit it, the dropdown is empty.

````
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" (click)="addAttribute()">Add Drop Down</a>
                </div>
        </div>```

       ``` <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="addFeatureForm" (ngSubmit)="onSaveFeature()">
        <div class="row" formArrayName="attributes"
            *ngFor="let attribute of addFeatureForm.get('attributes').controls; let i = index;">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3" [formGroupName]="i">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="nname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">ValidationType</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <angular2-multiselect [data]="validationTypeList" formControlName="validation" [(ngModel)]="attribute.selectedItems" 
                    [settings]="dropdownValidationSettings"></angular2-multiselect>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>```

        ```public addFeatureForm = this._fb.group({
            id: '',
            name: ['', Validators.required],
            icon: ['', Validators.required],
            type: ['', Validators.required],
            pattern: ['', Validators.required],
            matchType: ['', Validators.required],
            parent: null,
            attributes: this._fb.array([])
          });```
````

Comment: The problem is that you are mixing template driven forms with reactive forms. You do not use ngModel with reactive forms https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: More over, take account that the formControl in angular-2-multiselect is a FormControl, not a FormArray. `attributes:[[]]` NOT attributes:this._fb.array([]). Yes a FormControl can store an array